# Is it correct to make a request with a sentence that has if-clause but no then-clause?

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, sentence-patterns

I often hear sentences like these in online meetings:

> If you could move to the next slide please.

> If you could reply to that email.

Shouldn't these sentences be said like this:

> If you could move to the next slide, it would be helpful.

> If you could reply to that email, it would be helpful.

Are the first type of sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: I see it as an abbreviation of "If you could move to the next slide please, I would be grateful."  The intention is to be polite without too much repetition of gratitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not complete sentences; the implied meaning is, as you say, "It would be helpful if you..." People don't always speak in complete, grammatically correct sentences in everyday life.

Answer (score 1):

The first two sentences are conversational sentence in informal settings.....while the lower two are used in more formal and written settings...............